# Is there a way to have mediawiki show a list of the latest new pages that have been created?

Tags: mediawiki

Mediawiki has the great {{Special:Recent pages}} template that you can transclude to just show a certain number of pages. However, I'd like a simple list of the latest pages created by users to display on the home page. Is there a way to do this easily? Perhaps something with the dynamic lists extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at answers to this question ?

[Embedding Recent Changes on Main Page on MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419917/embedding-recent-changes-on-main-page-on-mediawiki)

You have several options :

- The Dynamic Article List extension
- The News extension
- Use the Semantic Media Wiki extension and query your pages using the Modified Date property