# Mediawiki: how to update page content from external script?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to update the Main_Page of our wiki from a script run by cron.

Apart from the page content itself, in `pagecontent.old_text`, what else do I need to update?

If I only update the "old_text" field, the new content is not displayed. I get the previous content, presumably from a cache somewhere. In `LocalSettings.php` I have `$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;`. So I guess that I need to also update something else in the Mediawiki database?

(In case it matters, this is with Mediawiki 1.31.10 on Debian 10 with Apache and PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the timestamp in `page.page_touched` works to have the wiki show the new content.

This example is using a PostgreSQL database, so it might need some adjustments if used with the more common MySQL DB.

To update the text of a page identified by it's name, it is necessary to join the `page`, `revision` and `pagecontent` tables. This example updates a page named "Drafts":

```sql
UPDATE pagecontent
SET old_text = 'New page content'
FROM page, revision
WHERE page.page_title='Drafts'
  AND pagecontent.old_id=revision.rev_text_id
  AND page.page_latest=revision.rev_id;
```

And to update the page timestamp so that the wiki shows the new content:

```sql
UPDATE "page"
SET page_touched = now()
WHERE page_namespace = '0'
  AND page_title = 'Drafts';
```

An alternative which avoids tinkering with the database directly, is to use an extension like [External Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data). There are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66124993/111036) to embed a text file in a page, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743265/111036) to embed the output of a database query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `maintenance/edit.php`, the [edit API](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit), [Pywikibot](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) etc. Trying to do changes via direct DB manipulation is a rather bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it might be risky to use the DB directly, particularly if an update changes something in the DB structure. But using the edit API or similar would create a new page revision at every update, which I don't want in this case of a daily update.

Comment: Just delete the old revision, there are scripts for that.